# Saving multiple impulse response functions in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I have run 5 seperate impulse response functions in R. I would like to save them in a dataframe to be able to plot using ggplot. Can anyone advise me on how to save them in a dataframe, as this is the only way to ggplot them?

I have reproduced my code below

```
# Reproduced Data (my dataframe which I'm estimating my VAR with is called "debt_arg")

structure(c(43.0909967382336, 26.9790446803372, 16.967092620984, 
29.5051405616314, 4.17318850227895, -4.84876355707382, -24.0607156164264, 
-17.9926676757792, -26.8046197351318, -39.2565717944843, -39.308523853837, 
-46.8804759131896, -89.3024279725422, -101.794380031895, -106.046332091248, 
-121.2682841506, -95.2702362099528, -62.4721882693054, -53.5841403286581, 
-38.7460923880107, -22.6580444473633, -42.4199965067158, -1.6919485660685, 
46.4060993745788, 27.4541473152261, 172.152195255873, 181.360243196521, 
176.898291137168, 309.076339077816, 336.794387018463, 196.02243495911, 
395.660482899758, 464.988530840405, 494.556578781053, 396.9146267217, 
505.832674662347, 524.940722602995, 519.918770543642, 420.396818484289, 
349.224866424937, 186.772914365584, 184.720962306232, 40.1990102468787, 
87.1570581875262, 42.2151061281736, -182.786845931179, -248.408797990532, 
-223.860750049884, -246.332702109237, -160.484654168589, -130.956606227942, 
-53.8285582872948, -69.6505103466475, -113.822462406, -119.124414465353, 
-71.5863665247052, -105.228318584058, -64.0802706434106, -111.022222702763, 
-40.9141747621159, -34.1361268214685, -92.7280788808212, -6.2500309401737, 
37.8680170004736, 60.686064941121, 101.094112881769, 103.382160822416, 
-74.1797912369368, -99.1317432962894, -228.933695355642, -534.125647414995, 
-654.007599474347, -688.0995515337, -617.091503593053, -501.913455652405, 
-462.655407711758, -405.577359771111, -539.759311830463, -464.641263889816, 
-370.263215949168, -338.035168008521, -361.017120067874, -495.649072127226, 
-418.951024186579, -349.762976245931, -393.074928305284, -331.696880364637, 
-305.778832423989, -232.140784483342, -150.822736542695, -116.134688602047, 
-30.4666406614001, -5.22859272075266, 86.9494552198946, 34.457503160542, 
108.705551101189, 158.723599041837, 141.341646982484, 55.3496949231317, 
-67.5222571362212, 72.7557908044264, 129.453838745074, 106.911886685721, 
222.349934626368, 289.877982567016, 368.006030507663, 454.244078448311, 
670.382126388958, 506.110174329605, 573.968222270253, 755.1862702109, 
363.624318151547, 664.462366092195, 414955.426174104, 410044.891543103, 
403034.35691006, 412023.822277016, 422013.287643972, 418102.753010928, 
435092.218377884, 438381.68374484, 432171.149111795, 445760.614478752, 
450850.079845708, 445939.545212663, 432029.01057962, 418218.475946575, 
394307.941313531, 372097.406680487, 346586.872047443, 319376.337414399, 
287765.802781355, 250555.268148311, 228444.733515267, 192634.198882223, 
142523.664249179, 114613.129616135, 73902.594983091, 52092.060350047, 
28781.5257170029, 13770.9910839589, -7139.54354908504, -31950.0781821292, 
-44460.6128151731, -55771.1474482173, -75681.6820812612, -101592.216714305, 
-120802.751347349, -125313.285980393, -155323.820613438, -190834.355246481, 
-219044.889879525, -244455.42451257, -247865.959145613, -249076.493778658, 
-245687.028411702, -244097.563044746, -271308.09767779, -282518.632310834, 
-301029.166943878, -301139.701576922, -301850.236209966, -287760.77084301, 
-300871.305476054, -316081.840109098, -312692.374742142, -328102.909375186, 
-330013.44400823, -348623.978641274, -380734.513274318, -393545.047907362, 
-409355.582540406, -429866.11717345, -451376.651806494, -483687.186439538, 
-509197.721072583, -531308.255705626, -548218.79033867, -577929.324971715, 
-593639.859604758, -618950.394237803, -628560.928870847, -622271.463503891, 
-592781.998136935, -507492.532769979, -501703.067403023, -474413.602036067, 
-482224.136669111, -509334.671302155, -507745.205935199, -506355.740568243, 
-473266.275201287, -424176.809834331, -399587.344467375, -322497.879100419, 
-207608.413733463, -169418.948366507, -145829.482999551, -99540.0176325953, 
-18950.5522656394, 8438.91310131643, 27528.3784682727, 34117.8438352286, 
87907.3092021844, 137896.77456914, 196686.239936097, 236275.705303052, 
240065.170670008, 288854.636036964, 325344.10140392, 340733.566770876, 
296223.032137832, 353212.497504788, 431101.962871744, 455291.4282387, 
519680.893605656, 551470.358972612, 591359.824339568, 664649.289706524, 
697038.75507348, 720028.220440436, 703717.685807392, 697007.151174348, 
717496.616541304, 716186.08190826, 728275.547275216, 1538.70118346597, 
2398.42391964878, 2392.09965578383, 4133.94339191895, 3777.72612805406, 
4867.33386418917, 4108.55160032429, 5550.94433645941, 4634.90307259452, 
5278.04380872964, 5088.51254486475, 7486.71828099987, 6869.96001713498, 
6070.3357532701, 4563.65148940522, 6128.08522554033, 2788.93596167545, 
2682.28969781056, 2229.84943394568, 3741.65917008079, 2630.38390621591, 
4082.16364235103, 2198.15237848614, 4896.45411462126, 4157.35585075637, 
4921.13358689149, 4820.0463230266, 6147.74805916172, 4105.90179529683, 
5193.46153143195, 3666.34326756707, 4597.95400370218, 1570.8447398373, 
2221.92547597241, 166.215212107527, 1763.06994824264, -1176.90431562224, 
-961.478579487128, -1735.65784335201, -1407.9491072169, -5683.92737108178, 
-5080.73563494666, -8825.40289881155, -6968.02316267644, -17166.0654265413, 
-20479.0666904062, -20975.0449542711, -19596.572218136, -18925.8824820009, 
-16613.6967458657, -16307.3730097306, -14033.8542735955, -13841.2785374604, 
-12716.7748013253, -13487.4250651902, -11195.5563290551, -12067.9225929199, 
-10807.5008567848, -10885.5221206497, -7810.93638451459, -10139.4426483795, 
-8558.90691224435, -8606.53717610924, -5071.93643997413, -6154.21470383901, 
-3857.6179677039, -5539.78023156878, 47.5015045663386, -3501.44675929855, 
-156.083023163432, 610.628712971687, 761.724449106798, -6687.22581475809, 
-6513.97907862297, -6552.17734248786, -671.552606352736, -4200.09687021763, 
-2435.65713408251, -933.942397947387, 10092.1733381877, 5412.08207432284, 
7628.10081045795, 7935.10854659307, 19198.7752827282, 11920.7060188633, 
17229.0047549984, 16831.0094911335, 31239.1312272686, 19334.4489634038, 
20324.2716995389, 20205.076435674, 26013.2221718091, 3328.73490794423, 
5991.50064407934, 6570.13238021445, 20323.7811163496, 11933.7938524847, 
15170.6605886198, 16821.4173247549, 13656.38206089, -8733.33720297486, 
-4910.67546683973, -7102.64173070462, 6088.80900543051, 663.179741565611, 
1739.09747770072, 216.726213835747, 8738.72494997097, -3065.35931389393, 
-12117.1165777588, -29574.4198416237, -23324.9971054886, -32336.0323693535, 
270.48, 265.24, 652.73, 800.62, 747.79, 660.42, 419.8, 426.33, 
420.66, 412.91, 487.09, 581.92, 558.75, 519.1, 604.55, 460.49, 
382.46, 405.58, 431.74, 518.96, 509.36, 607.4, 558.86, 649.37, 
706.08, 809.41, 822.47, 687.5, 709.97, 550.44, 380.28, 430.06, 
419.78, 498.72, 534.4, 550.47, 569.24, 496.9, 475.42, 416.77, 
443.81, 402.25, 243.55, 295.39, 436.13, 350.65, 395.19, 524.95, 
566.46, 765.61, 827.69, 1071.96, 1201.66, 945.45, 1142.5, 1375.37, 
1400.42, 1367.41, 1694.83, 1543.31, 1800.58, 1711.09, 1637.27, 
2090.46, 2102.78, 2190.87, 2187.97, 2151.73, 2103.72, 2107.87, 
1598.17, 1079.66, 1125.95, 1587.97, 2075.14, 2320.73, 2373.71, 
2185.01, 2643.42, 3523.59, 3388.03, 3360.64, 2463.63, 2462.63, 
2683.99, 2346.68, 2451.73, 2854.29, 3380.78, 2976.27, 4783.77, 
5391.03, 6373.82, 7887.33, 12548.99, 8597.02, 10837.23, 11656.81, 
9814.62, 11675.18, 12992.43, 14683.49, 16675.68, 16917.86, 20265.32, 
21912.63, 26078.29, 30065.61, 31108.86, 26037.01, 33461.77, 30292.55, 
33466.03, 3.26e+08, 2.1e+07, 1.1e+07, 7.869e+09, 862806000, 538167500, 
476328500, 157505500, 731948111.111111, 24350957088.2353, 999682500, 
4203927088.23529, 1806496171.11111, 164884528.235294, 2178749500, 
2576536163.86555, -1104639488.88889, 1183937108.57143, 1323054635.48522, 
2240739607.7745, 3231203531.20524, 2224656303.03667, 2799743875.36837, 
2852285791.5461, 4248938759.38433, 1762499191.62355, 2765832512.19452, 
1498329486.02275, 3436536228.02919, 4467813458.46352, 2844847427.10581, 
153779772.547889, 768245951.027719, 2874603185.30815, 84905815.7334787, 
2265403119.14626, 2444297843.45995, 1369023915.06914, -253538732.407444, 
-1664050535.17686, -2690301300.23777, -1596956359.91031, -2925302741.22981, 
-2533781832.48488, -2258880000, -1220300000, 142670000, -1664830000, 
-2036900000, -2134950000, -497270000, -3059160000, -3754980000, 
-1132040000, -2212520000, -2153150000, -3101240000, -728950000, 
991330000, 1156170000, 2753260645.58738, 1910464819.74444, 852896475.94148, 
2277112718.5433, 2022087685.81889, 5273568557.49061, -1502521294.35984, 
1063441737.14022, -226518951.379118, -1253194355.76109, -2177171727.73634, 
-1535518403.57232, 96147441.6142862, -296349372.551493, -627558644.109443, 
-467930782.724932, 405257699.151905, 144634171.908078, 337338547.911262, 
1859566805.68781, 796934898.126637, 286707726.576741, -236299720.277408, 
-887533002.579341, 1553120015.26578, 27003236.9796999, -1454448585.92745, 
124239641.731611, 168476951.081102, -568202127.603569, -253500911.561899, 
1240493061.28016, 1162373441.80884, -4349136882.03693, 540850191.216397, 
63371068.2983998, 1134211263.74247, 1367030943.20801, 618885142.028415, 
-2829317497.3944, 4728966886.53824, 12590576935.5312, 6879440409.39944, 
10868932518.4022, 15553076839.5202, 4374233548.15403, 6179975808.64763, 
12303491605.5898, 16348265006.8077, -1264432453.55569, -1071543953.94089, 
-728949104.179213, 519284160.862738, 0, 0, 0, 0, 321395635.417275, 
-27163751.5253196, 578208608.58746, 341330056.878433, 253612251.627469, 
407474140.566744, 3485218027.37565, 1524948883.60027, 1095063503.93567, 
-243667941.737244, 2303448152.30374, 1065446917.68978, 637179622.619144, 
414989651.653276, 57287900.1825424, 442961505.748743, 614615523.155122, 
474062261.101183, -528254493.861979, 306917257.290977, 466868012.120676, 
91074750.1073804, 1873300034.41525, -111963691.48737, 562133833.756524, 
-499826456.669203, -65715454.514262, -206227359.32734, -95642879.0800113, 
-10545930096.3757, -309843542.700806, 178698848.75935, 281636981.229176, 
-94039364.237304, -3456799000.38897, 42016298.5163033, 29986452.0184, 
-34745156.95985, -69089531.8771083, 104975191.0695, 3880000, 
18160000, -1.2e+07, -125920000, 49020000, 19960000, -67760000, 
64130000, -60730000, 32580000, -11850000, -46150000, -3340000, 
-34610000, -67770000, 57620000, 247065572.305654, 110723963.408605, 
132149695.892849, 216716497.314816, 549906355.874947, 594931451.444728, 
228472127.27772, 411625076.952925, -92909673.1325036, -202873018.788848, 
-58179792.5150349, -176659291.195054, -73100388.2223938, 10404172.6882247, 
-54286803.4483821, -94934845.5623686, -215442207.120147, -82511407.2007654, 
95972418.060002, 130964874.692201, -51017265.9840873, 85839986.5801663, 
126620883.760985, -369639265.12419, -29215440.7294261, -11121692.0314486, 
-115981397.706632, 21410812.1712994, 79654137.3840613, 27308434.4325477, 
-4229545.44216412, 239144758.016801, 14686931.9932968, 231275172.573391, 
66295018.1798717, -94357525.4859095, 41697675.4063964, 22833247.3850187, 
-44701305.1208689, 219281935.220203, 29548818.0680997, 38598506.304463, 
417521774.71664, 499547569.881022, 50027913.0234979, 852409184.207933, 
1596119677.49392, 514743198.781707, 102026577.988947, -292454396.807919, 
-130885581.879457, -187033564.604513, 195110655.737268), .Dim = c(113L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("sp", "m1_us", "m1_arg", "eq_arg", 
"pfdebt_arg", "pfequity_arg")), .Tsp = c(1991, 2019, 4), class = c("mts", 
"ts", "matrix"))
```

```r
# Estimate VAR Model

var.est.debt_arg <- VAR(debt_arg,p=1,type="both",season=NULL)
summary(var.est.debt_arg)

# Impulse Response Functions

debtarg_1 <- irf(var.est.debt_arg,response="pfdebt_arg",impulse="sp",n.ahead=40,ortho=TRUE,boot=TRUE)
plot(debtarg_1) # response of pfdebt to s&p shock

debtarg_2 <- irf(var.est.debt_arg,response="pfdebt_arg",impulse="m1_us",n.ahead=40,ortho=TRUE,boot=TRUE)
plot(debtarg_2) # response of pfdebt to us M1 Shock

debtarg_3 <- irf(var.est.debt_arg,response="pfdebt_arg",impulse="m1_arg",n.ahead=40,ortho=TRUE,boot=TRUE)
plot(debtarg_3) # response of pfdebt to a domestic m1 shock

debtarg_4 <- irf(var.est.debt_arg,response="pfdebt_arg",impulse="eq_arg",n.ahead=40,ortho=TRUE,boot=TRUE)
plot(debtarg_4) # response of pfdebt to equity market price shock

debtarg_5 <- irf(var.est.debt_arg,response="pfdebt_arg",impulse="pfequity_arg",n.ahead=40,ortho=TRUE,boot=TRUE)
plot(debtarg_5) # response of pfdebt to pfequity shocks
```

I would like to plot these 5 IRFs using GGPlot and GridExtra. I'm looking to plot each IRF in grid format in a row

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Tanga94, i noticed you post another question. In my answer to your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59335309/plotting-impulse-response-functions-in-grid-format, there is a part to get the data.frame

Comment: Does it not work for you?

Comment: Hi @StupidWolf, I tried it now and it works. Thank you so much, highly appreciate it!